# Issues with django-admin.py makemessages -l en

Tags: django, django-multilingual

I want to use **multiple languages** in my app

I do not want a locale file for english inside LOCALE folder but by mistake i have create this using this

`django-admin.py makemessages -l en`

so Please tell me how can I remove this 'en' folder which I have creates.
Because now if i try to create language folder for another language using this `django-admin.py makemessages -l es` it does not create.

WHY SO???

Comment: Are you sure the two things are related and that 'es' doesn't work because 'en' exists ? It seems strange. Do you have any error messages when you run django-admin.py makemessages -l es ? Is the LOCALE directory writable ?

Comment: its my mistake I restart the server and now 'es' is created but django.po file is not writable when writes something i it such as 
`msgid "Hello"
msgstr "¡hola"`
And try to upload it there is an error of "critical file transfer error"

Comment: If I get it correctly, you're developing directly on some server, using a server environment and security policies. Why aren't you developing locally using Django's development server (and then upload it to a production server later) ? It has been created specially to avoid that kind of headaches.

Comment: I have tried it in local server then there is no django.po file is created by default in my 'es' folder i have to create that manually and I created it and put the desired msg in it and compiled it but it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no relation between having an english "en" directory in locale, and "es" not being created.

Secondly, if you want to remove en you could just remove that by rm -r en/

And es, as you are trying to do, has several variants.
probably you could try giving a a particular variant. This will help you with language codes. http://www.science.co.il/language/locale-codes.asp